# 415 error when trying to access UMLS API via R vs Postman

Tags: r, postman, httr

I can successfully hit the endpoints for the UMLS authentication via Postman, but keep getting 415 errors when moving this code to R and using httr. This only seems to work when using x-www-form-urlencoded (as opposed to json).

My relevant Postman headers are:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded and
Accept: /*/

And trying to recreate this in R:

```
library(httr)
auth_endpoint <- "https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/v1/api-key"
auth_headers <- c("Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                  "Accept" = "*/*")

getTGT <- function(endpoint, headers) {
  request_body <- list(apikey = "API_KEY_HERE")
  request <- POST(url = endpoint,
                  headers = add_headers(.headers = headers),
                  body = request_body
}
```

This request is returning the 415 error which I can only tell is related to the Content-Type. I am more used to using JSON but that doesn't work in Postman either. Am I creating the request body correctly for a x-www-form-urlencoded type?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out - for x-www-form-urlencoded content, there needs to be encode = 'form' included in the POST call.